# SSAS / MDX Query - Get month-by-month data for an item

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a query:

```
SELECT  
NON EMPTY   { [Item].[123] } ON COLUMNS,
            { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
FROM        [Sales Analysis]
```

This returns the total amount sold for an item called "123". What I'd like to do is split this up so that I'm able to see the total sold for each month of the calender year. Something like:

```
SELECT  
NON EMPTY   { [Time].[Year].[Calender 2011].Children, [Item].[123] } ON COLUMNS,
            { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
FROM        [Sales Analysis]
```

But this doesn't work as I intend to do, I just cant get the query right. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I've also tried this, but to no avail:

```
SELECT  
NON EMPTY   { [Time].[Year].[Calender 2011].Children } ON COLUMNS,
            { [Total Line Value] } ON ROWS
FROM        [Sales Analysis]
WHERE       [Item].[123]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
NON EMPTY   { [Time].[Year].[Calender 2011].Children } ON COLUMNS,
            { [Item].[123] } ON ROWS
FROM        [Sales Analysis]
WHERE       [Measures].[Total Line Value]
```

Comment: Hi again Max, I actually solved it by doing: SELECT {[Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Year].&[2011-01-01T00:00:00].Children} ON COLUMNS , 
{[Product].[Item].&[123]} ON ROWS  
FROM [Sales Analysis] WHERE [Measures].[Total Line Value] .

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for [Item].[123] looks odd - Is this shorthand? Normally for a single member the syntax would be [Dimension].[Attribute].[Item123]? I'd expect your query 3 to work as expected otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Use crossjoin:

```
SELECT  
NON EMPTY   {{[Time].[Year].[Calender 2011].Children} * {[Item].[123]}} ON COLUMNS,
            {[Total Line Value]} ON ROWS
FROM        [Sales Analysis]
```